# Python- Solving code by hand?

Tags: python

My professor wants us to solve this code and several other ones that are similar by hand. Since I'm new to programming I have no clue how to do that at all and I'm completely lost

```
num = 0

for i in range(2,5):
    for j in range(-1, 1):
        num = num*j + i
        print("i =", i, "j =", j, "num =", num)
```

Comment: Didn't your professor teach you this during class? Do you have any lecture notes? Which books have you read? Have you asked your professor?

Comment: Read this: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: Solving by hand seems like a fine skill, but if you're not supposed to run it, you're probably not supposed to ask (kindly) strangers on the internet either :) Look up Python for loops, print statements, assignment statements, and the range function, to start

Comment: Well I think your professor wants you to dubug your code in your mind which would be really helpful for you. And it would better if ask some specific question were you are actually stuck in and tried .

Comment: If you can't get help from your professor, then you can still learn Python from elsewhere. For example, this is for beginners: http://www.codecademy.com/ (select to Python class).

Comment: @pts no he has not taught it which is why I am very lost. I tried looking up things but I just don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take a stab at this.

```
for i in range(2,5):
  for j in range(-1, 1):
```

translates to

2

-1, 0

3

-1, 0

4

-1, 0

Why? the for loop says "For each number in the range of 2 to 5 (not including 5) do SOMETHING"
That something is another loop.

"For the number 2, give me the range of -1 to 1 (not including 1).

After that its just some basic math.

num = 0 * -1 + 2 = 2 (new value of num is now 2, not the original 0, remember this going to next iteration)

num = 2 * 0 + 2 = 2

num = 2 * -1 +3 = 1

etc

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way.

This is your code:

```
num = 0

for i in range(2,5):
    for j in range(-1, 1):
        num = num*j + i
        print("i =", i, "j =", j, "num =", num)
```

`range(2, 5) = [2, 3, 4]` and `range(-1, 1) = [-1, 0]`, So:

```
num = 0

for i in [2, 3, 4]:
    for j in [-1, 0]:
        num = num*j + i
        print("i =", i, "j =", j, "num =", num)
```

---

Now for the first iteration, `i = 2`, `j = -1` and `num = 0`, So:

```
num = 0 * -1 + 2 = 0 + 2 = 2
      ^    ^   ^
      |    |   |
     num   j   i
```

So, the print statement `print("i =", i, "j =", j, "num =", num)` would print the following:

```
"i = 2 j = -1 num = 2"
```

---

For the second iteration, `i = 2`, `j = 0` and `num = 2`, So:

```
num = 2 * 0 + 2 = 0 + 2 = 2
      ^   ^   ^
      |   |   |
     num  j   i
```

So, the print statement `print("i =", i, "j =", j, "num =", num)` would print the following:

```
"i = 2 j = 0 num = 2"
```

---

For the third iteration, `i = 3`, `j = -1` and `num = 2`, So:

```
num = 2 * -1 + 3 = -2 + 3 = 1
      ^    ^   ^
      |    |   |
     num   j   i
```

So, the print statement `print("i =", i, "j =", j, "num =", num)` would print the following:

```
"i = 3 j = -1 num = 1"
```

---

Altogether your print statements would look like this:

```
"i = 2 j = -1 num = 2"
"i = 2 j = 0 num = 2"
"i = 3 j = -1 num = 1"
"i = 3 j = 0 num = 3"
"i = 4 j = -1 num = 1"
"i = 5 j = 0 num = 4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would follow the program:

```
#A
num = 0
#B
for i in range(2,5):
    for j in range(-1, 1):
        #C
        num = num*j + i
        #D
        print("i =", i, "j =", j, "num =", num)
        #E
```

- A: num is undefined, i is undefined, j is undefined.
- B: num is 0, i is undefined, j is undefined.
- C: num is 0, i is 2, j is -1.
- D: num is 2, i is 2, j is -1.
- E: same as D, but this just got printed: `i = 2, j = -1, num = 2`
- C: num is 2, i is 2, j is 0.
- ...

Comment: how does "j" in C become "0"

Comment: @Caroline Rodgers: After E we go back to C, because `for` loops haven't terminated yet. First the `for j` loop is incrementing j. `range(-1, 1)` means the integers `-1 <= j < 1`, and the previous value was -1, so the next value is 0. There won't be any more values for j, so the next time in C, i will be incremented (from 2 to 3), and j will restart at -1.